# For what reason when I use environment variables returns error?

Tags: python, environment-variables

I expect both cases returned the same message, but only the first is correct

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.path.isdir('/home/macabeus/ApenasMeu')
True
>>> os.path.isdir('~/ApenasMeu')
False
```

For which reason the second does not handle the `~`? How to solve this problem?

Comment: There isn't actually any environment variable here.

Comment: @tripleee The `~` is not an environment variable?

Comment: No.  In the shell, it's a shorthand to refer to the value of `$HOME`, but this is not shell.

Comment: So the environment variable is the `$HOME`? Or no?

Comment: The corresponding environment variable which you are not using here is named `$HOME`, yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To quote the [`os.path` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html):

> Unlike a unix shell, Python does not do any automatic path expansions. Functions such as [`expanduser()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser) and [`expandvars()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.expandvars) can be invoked explicitly when an application desires shell-like path expansion. (See also the `glob` module.)

So you can use those functions to perform that expansion:

```
>>> os.path.expanduser('~/ApenasMeu')
'/home/macabeus/ApenasMeu'
>>> os.path.isdir(os.path.expanduser('~/ApenasMeu'))
True
```